# custom ListView adapter not showing the text

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

i have a `ListView` and i populate the list from `<string-array name="list_items">` in `values/strings.xml`, and as shown below, I created my cutomed `Array Adapter` that extends `BaseAdapter`. I expected when I ran the App. to see the `listView` is populated as te following according to the below mentioed `item.xml`:

1-an icon "the same icon for the entire list items", 
2-the strings i retrieved from the `resources` folder, 
3-and the word "description" "this word should be the same for the entire list items".

But what happens is, when i run the App. step number two is not showing at all. what I am missing in the code.

**MyAdapter**:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> mArraList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mArraList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mArraList = mArraList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.mArraList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.mArraList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        }

         ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
         TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
         TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);

         for (int i = 0; i < MyAdapter.this.getCount(); i++) {
             txtCount.setText(MyAdapter.this.getItem(i).toString()); 
         }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**item.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**MainActivity**:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_items);
        mArraList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            mArraList.add(listItems[i]);
        }

        adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mArraList);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that *mArraList* is not empty?

Comment: why `for (int i = 0; i < MyAdapter.this.getCount(); i++) {
         txtCount.setText(MyAdapter.this.getItem(i).toString()); 
     }`?

Comment: (replace that with `txtCount.setText(getItem(position).toString())`, for example)

Comment: @njzk2 yes i tried you suggestion even before i post the question, bu the result is he sae

Answer (score 0):

Remove the for loop first, it is not servinng any purpose as I think.

And try this to set the text -

`txtCount.setText((String)mArraList.get(position));`

This should work. Your layout and everything else is fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forget use context initialize you Relative Layout in adapter, here is code

```
MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> mArraList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mArraList) {
  this.context = context;
  this.mArraList = mArraList;
  this.layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mArraList.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mArraList.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
 }

 ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
 TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
 TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);

 for (int i = 0; i < MyAdapter.this.getCount(); i++) {
     txtCount.setText(MyAdapter.this.getItem(i).toString()); 
 }
return convertView;
 }
 }
```

Comment: that changes what, exactly?

Comment: private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;  this.layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);                  convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

Comment: but what is wrong with `LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`, and how do you reckon this can solve the OP's problem?